# SQL Query - Select numbers where last 7 digits are identical

Tags: sql-server, select, substring

I have a table in SQL full of numbers made of 13 digits.

I want to write a query that selects all **numbers** with the **last 7 digits** being **identical**.

For example :

Out of these:

```
2547041010012
2547042003000
2547041111111
2547042011100
2547040000000
```

Selects these:

```
2547040000000
2547041111111
```

How can I write this query?
Do I use **SUBSTRING(mo,7,7)** ?

*where SUBSTRING(mo,7,7) = ??*

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are they identical? You mean the last 7 digits should be the same digit?

Comment: Yes all the numbers that end with the same last 7 digits @christiandev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE LEN (REPLACE(RIGHT(mo,7), RIGHT(mo,1), '') ) = 0
```

or

```
WHERE RIGHT(mo,7) NOT LIKE '%[^' + RIGHT(mo,1) + ']%'
```

or

```
WHERE mo LIKE '%' + REPLICATE (RIGHT(mo,1), 7)
```

I would prefer 3rd solution.

Comment: first one should be = 0?

Comment: @OGHaza Everything after the number "4" should be the same. Last 7 digits.

Comment: Yes I know, both these solutions work correctly but I think the first one should be = 0 not = 1 (otherwise it matches when exactly 6 of the last 7 characters are the same)

Comment: @OGHaza Sorry. In 1st one there should be 0. Fixed.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut In second one I check that last 7 symbols do not contain anything exept the last symbol.

Comment: @GriGrim in the third one it might return all values with numbers repeated 7 times but not necessarily in order. So they won't have to be last 7..

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Why not last 7? I do not put the percent sign at the end of like statement. For example if `mo` is `'2547041111111'` then where clause would be similar to `WHERE mo LIKE '%1111111'` which says that we need such `mo` that ends with seven ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define your list of numbers and then join against that...(but @GriGrim [`solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950360/1449181) is much cleaner :)) - I only added this as an alternate in case this was a one off query and may be faster (depending on your query execution plan).

```
DECLARE @nums TABLE (num BIGINT)
DECLARE @allowednums TABLE (num BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @nums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2547041010012 )
        INSERT INTO @nums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2547042003000 )
        INSERT INTO @nums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2547041111111 )
        INSERT INTO @nums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2547042011100 )
        INSERT INTO @nums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2547040000000 )

INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 0000000 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 1111111 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 2222222 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 3333333 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 4444444 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 5555555 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 6666666 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 7777777 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 8888888 )
        INSERT INTO @allowednums
        ( num ) VALUES ( 9999999 )

SELECT  [@nums].num
FROM    @nums
        INNER JOIN @allowednums ON CAST(right(CAST([@nums].num AS VARCHAR(20)), 7) AS INT) = [@allowednums].num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_with_number
from table_with_column
where right(column_with_number,7) in (
    '0000000',
    '1111111',
    '2222222',
    '3333333',
    '4444444',
    '5555555',
    '6666666',
    '7777777',
    '8888888',
    '9999999'
)
```